# Как правильно написать супер дружелюбный?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать супер дружелюбный в предложении, вроде: Он супер дружелюбный человек? Раздельно или слитно?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

**Супердружелюбный**. Супер - приставка иноязычного происхождения, пишется с прилагательным, как и с существительным, слитно. Вот ответ Грамоты.ру:

> Вопрос № 266024     Как правильно писать:  Супер/ Ультраосветляющие
>   оттенки?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка Верно: **суперосветляющие,**
>   ультраосветляющие; супер- и ультраосветляющие.